# Pull to Refresh TableView in Domino To Go

Tags: titanium, dominotogo

Is there a way to setup "pull to refresh" with Domino to Go JSON data? I have been looking at this widget specifically: https://github.com/FokkeZB/nl.fokkezb.pullToRefresh.

It appears that a model/collection is required for the pull to refresh widget above. How would this integrate with the JSON data that is generated from Domino to Go?

Answer (score 1):

No problem at all. Look at this Alloy based code:

```
<View layout="vertical"  height="Ti.UI.SIZE" width="Ti.UI.FILL" top="0" left="0">
<View id="SyncControl" layout="horizontal" height="Ti.UI.SIZE" width="Ti.UI.FILL"> 
  <SearchBar id="navigation_query" clearButtonMode="1" onReturn="events_runquery" showCancel="true" onCancel="events_cancel" autocorrect="false" hintText="Namensteil oder Ort eingeben"/>
</View>
<TableView id="navigation_table" onClick="events_click" top="2">
    <Widget id="ptr" src="nl.fokkezb.pullToRefresh" onRelease="events_pullRefresh" />
</TableView>
</View>
```

and in the controller:

```
function events_pullRefresh(e) {
  sync();
}
```

sync():

```
function sync() {
    try {
        if (!Ti.Network.online) {
            YN.log("sync: no network.");
            return;
        }
        if (!Alloy.Globals.notesdb) {
            DTG.UI.alert(ynL("sync9"));
            return;
        }
        Alloy.Globals.syncInProgress = true;
        var view = Alloy.Globals.notesdb.getView("(mobile_companies)");
        view.update(sync_contacts, false, 'Sync failed: %s', {progressCallback : sync_progress});
    } catch (e) {
        DTG.exception("sync -> sync", e);
    }
}
```

So, pretty easy, actually :-)

Comment: I'm able to get the view to update with the above example, but how can we get the hide method to run after a successful update? Currently the widget will stay "Updating" (http://i.imgur.com/7HntKUD.png?1)

In the widget example he attaches the hide method to the collection,  but we do not have a collection to attach to.

Comment: in my case it seems to work without calling a hide method... but if the widget has an hide method, you can call it from the callback you gave the NotesView.update() (in my example: sync_contacts).

Comment: I have my code I am trying to use here: https://gist.github.com/rbuening28/b98f55df59a030608314. I have my comment where my issue is. Where am I going wrong?